RAM tester circuitry
There are RAM testers out there that test the connection between RAM pin and Motherboard slot.

The way it operates is very simple. Between a pin and ground plane is a SMD-LED and a resistor. As long as there is a connection current flows through the pin-trace and lights up the LED.
There is another version of a RAM tester that works the 'opposite way' and I have been trying to figure out the way it works for hours. LEDs stay off for as long as there is a connection between Motherboard slot and RAM pin. A severed connection will cause the LED to light up.


Zooming in, I can spot the following mock circuit.
PIN3 -- LED -- R -- 3V --
It looks like a floating connection on the left side of the LED, how can it light up?
BACKSIDE:


please add a picture of the other side

@jsotola the back side is void of anything

V+ ---////-----x------|led>|-----gnd .... connect x to gnd to turn off LED

When a detection is made either a 1 or 0, the voltage can be applied to the Anode (+) for "positive logic" thru the R to 0V or to the Cathode (-) thru the R to V+ for "negative" or inverted logic".
Thus you can make it light up in either input state.

So how does the electricity travel here when it's a 0? I am trying to follow the trace and I am lost

If + side of LED , R is fixed to V+ then 0 to -ve side turns it on

I think I get it now, thank you.
